# Output should look like a quotation

Tags: python, quotation-marks

I am trying to print a quotation and the name of the author. My output should look something like the following (including the quotation):

> Albert Einstein once said, "A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."

I tried this:

```
quote = "A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."
message = f"Albert Einstein once said, {quote}"
print(message)
```

But I am not getting quotation, the rest is fine I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
>>> quote = "\"A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new.\""
>>> message = f"Albert Einstein once said, {quote}"
>>> print(message)
Albert Einstein once said, "A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."
```

Or you can also do something like this:

```
>>> quote = "A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."
>>> message = f"Albert Einstein once said, \"{quote}\""
>>> print(message)
Albert Einstein once said, "A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."
```

Or you can wrap the double quotes with a single quote to get you to print the double quotes.

Do something like this:

```
>>> quote = '"A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."'
>>> message = f"Albert Einstein once said, {quote}"
>>> print(message)
Albert Einstein once said, "A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."
```

Note that if you have a single quote inside your sentence, then it will not work. For example, if your sentence said
`"A person who's never made a mistake never tried anything new"`, then the single quote won't work.

Comment: This perfectly shows the usage of special char, although i think it's a bit complicated to look at.

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
quote = '"A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."'
message = "Albert Einstein once said, {}".format(quote)
print(message)
```

Comment: this wont print the quotation marks. You are not explicitly asking it to print the quotation mark.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 quote = '"A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."'
 message = f"Albert Einstein once said, {quote}"
 print(message)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
a = "Albert Einstein once said, \"A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new.\""
print(a)
```

or:

```
a = 'Albert Einstein once said,"A person who never made a mistake never tried anything new."'
print(a)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need put backslash before the quotation marks.

```
print("test test hello /" very good /" said him")
```

Output:

> test test hello " very good " said him

Comment: still no getting brother, can you please share the code?

Comment: Oh ok, pls wait a sec.

Comment: always add some explanation with some example(code) as to why you choose this solution.